# sed command to replace multi digit with line number

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have contact list.

e.g

```
aashish 7905209890  
abhishek    9129429439  
anmol   918416973189    
avinash 917068575283
```

I want to replace every phone number with line number.

I want to replace 1st phone number with 1, 2nd phone number with 2, 3rd no. with 3 etc.

Comment: Monu Rajbgar, welcome do Unix & Linux SE. What have you tried so far? Usually awk, perl are good for this kind of tasks,

Answer (score 2):

Using `gawk` you can use this:

```bash
gawk -i inplace '{print $1, NR}' your_contact_list.txt
```

Usually in Linux distributions the `awk` command is a symbolic link to `gawk`. So you can simply do:

```bash
awk -i inplace '{print $1, NR}' your_contact_list.txt
```

But it seems that `awk -i inplace` is not POSIX compliant, because if you use: `awk --posix -i inplace` the following error will be shown:

```
awk: inplace:30: @load "inplace"
awk: inplace:30:  ^ syntax error
```

So you can use:

```bash
awk '{print $1, NR}' your_contact_list.txt > new_contact_list.txt
```

**Note:** If you are going to print only the first and second column with the default delimiter (a space) you can use `'{print $1, NR}'`. That will print the first column (e.g `aashish`) and the current number line with a space between both strings.

If you want to specify any string between both columns, then you can set the field delimiter with `-v OFS='some string'` on the awk command line:

```
awk -i inplace -v OFS=' -- ' '{print $1, NR}' your_contact_list.txt
#Output:
aashish -- 1
abhishek -- 2
anmol -- 3
avinash -- 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) one-liner:

```
$ perl -i -lane 'print "$F[0] $."' file
$ cat file
aashish 1
abhishek 2
anmol 3
avinash 4
```